# Animating a CSS car with charge filling from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have designed front fascia of a car in CSS, and I would like to animate it from bottom to top, with charge filling in. How can I achieve that?
I am able to fill the bottom section of the car with it, but I want to do it for the whole car.
Any sort of suggestion/help will be highly appreciated. Please find the code for the same below,

```css
.car-top {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 150px solid #555;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    height: 0;
    width: 350px;
}

.car-bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #555;
}

.car-bottom:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #04ACFF;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: wipe 2s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
}

.tires:before, .tires:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 80px;
    background: #555;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;   
}

.tires:before {
    left: 0;
}

.tires:after {
    right: 0;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="car-top"></div>
    <div class="car-bottom">
        <div class="tires"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a mask of some kind but frankly an SVG would be easier.

Comment: You'd have to animate each of your car components independently with appropriate delays. The problem is that you've used pseudo-elements for the shapes. If you rework your markup to use actual elements for all shapes you could then animate pseudo-elements over the top of each. I'm not sure that's worth doing, though, so I'm not providing an answer. There are better ways.

Answer (score 4):

SVG clip path works best for this. (I just borrowed the SVG from Font Awesome; you can change it as you like.)

```css
#svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.car {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #555;
  clip-path: url(#car);
}

.car::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #04ACFF;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: wipe 2s cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4) forwards;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.-->
  <clipPath id="car" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.001953125, 0.001953125)">
    <path d="M135.2 117.4L109.1 192H402.9l-26.1-74.6C372.3 104.6 360.2 96 346.6 96H165.4c-13.6 0-25.7 8.6-30.2 21.4zM39.6 196.8L74.8 96.3C88.3 57.8 124.6 32 165.4 32H346.6c40.8 0 77.1 25.8 90.6 64.3l35.2 100.5c23.2 9.6 39.6 32.5 39.6 59.2V400v48c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32H448c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V400H96v48c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32H32c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V400 256c0-26.7 16.4-49.6 39.6-59.2zM128 288a32 32 0 1 0 -64 0 32 32 0 1 0 64 0zm288 32a32 32 0 1 0 0-64 32 32 0 1 0 0 64z"></path>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<div class="car"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My own approach would be to avoid the artistry of HTML and CSS, and instead use an SVG along with the CSS `image-mask` property, as follows:

```css
/* defining the animation, with the @keyframes property: */
@keyframes fill {
  /* the initial state is the current state of the element,
     so we only have to animate to that final state: */
  to {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
  }
}

html {
  block-size: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, hsl(120deg 40% 5% / 1), hsl(120deg 80% 5%));
  block-size: 100vb;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  block-size: 100%;
  /* using grid layout for the ease of centering the content in
     the page: */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

/* 
  Attribution, this SVG is currently hosted on my own site but was originally sourced from:
    https://svgsilh.com/image/2736805.html
  and released under CC0 license (see: https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/deed.en)
*/
.car {
  /* the color to show when the 'car' is filled: */
  --filled: hsl(240deg 100% 60% / 1);
  /* the color to show when the 'car' is not yet filled: */
  --unfilled: black;
  /* shorthand for:
    animation-name: fill;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(...);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  */
  animation: fill 10s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4) forwards;
  /* sizing the element, so that its inline-axis is 1.6 times the (defined)
     block-size of the element: */
  aspect-ratio: 1.6;
  /*
    shorthand for:
      background-image: linear-gradient(...);
      background-position: 50% 0;
      background-size: 100% 200%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    this allows us to position the linear-gradient 50% on the horizontal axis, and zero
    on the vertical axis (so far, I don't think that logical properties are available to
    background-position unfortunately), and specify the background-image to be 100% of
    the width of the element, and 200% of the vertical height of the parent element:
  */
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, var(--unfilled) 0 50%, var(--filled) 50%) 50% 0 / 100% 200% no-repeat;
  /* defining the block-size to be 60 viewport-block units, right-to-left/top-to-bottom languages,
     this is equivalent to height, but using logical properties to allow for sizing according to the
     user's language preferences: */
  block-size: 60vb;
  /* using the url() function to load the SVG: */
  mask-image: url(//davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/mask.svg);
  /* positioning the SVG in the center of the element: */
  mask-position: 50% 50%;
  /* setting the SVG to be sized as large as possible without overflowing the element: */
  mask-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="car"></div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zke4j0o6/1/).

References:

- [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).
- [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).
- [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration).
- [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).
- [`animation-name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name).
- [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).
- [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).
- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).
- [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).
- [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image).
- [`mask-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-position).
- [`mask-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-size).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid answer, but you can leave your shape as is (almost) and "fill" it with color using `mix-blend-mode`:

```css
.car-top {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 150px solid #555;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  height: 0;
  width: 350px;
}

.car-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #555;
}

.car-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #04ACFF;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.tires{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.tires:before,
.tires:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background: #555;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.tires:before {
  left: 0;
}

.tires:after {
  right: 0;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: wipe 2s cubic-bezier(.2,.6,.8,.4) forwards;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 6;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  to{
    transform:translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="car-top"></div>
  <div class="car-bottom"></div>
  <div class="tires"></div>
</div>
```